# My project in Angular does not work a Deploy on none platform

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, deployment

I did a project in angular with firebase firestore, and now i want to deploy this application, but when i deploy in platforms like Netlify, Heroku, Firebase, my app appear all white, whereby in local this app works correctly.

Thats is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Restaurante</title>
<link rel="icon" class="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/envolti-dark.png">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

and this is my app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My rotes works correctly also, that is my code:

app-routing.module.ts:

[app-routing.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTgpa.png)

Thanks all for de help!

my files is that:
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNKDD.png)

Comment: You need use [`ng build`](https://angular.io/cli/build) -and upload the "dist" folder. See that in your index.html you need to have the bundles files (the .js and the .css)

Comment: But in my Angular app, i have many components, so how i deploy that? I added an image of my files, and they don't have the dist folder, should I put my entire application in it?

Comment: Check here how to do it (https://angular.io/guide/deployment)